# Derogatory name for Average Joe type

Tags: single-word-requests, nicknames

I am looking for a derogatory name (not aggressive or distasteful, just a bit derogatory). Let me explain: In my country, there are these kind of average people who think they are great and know everything, and have a really bad attitude towards everything and everyone they consider "inferior", and yet they are considered ridiculous by everyone.

So it's not the same concept as "Average Joe", but an "Average Joe who thinks he's not average". The term that comes closest is Joe Schmoe, but I think there must be a more apt word.

Preferably, it needs to be a name. This is for a character we wrote in Spanish, but the name does not translate at all.

Comment: Too vague. If you want a name for something, specify clearly what that something is. That's the starting point: clear thought. Words come later.

Comment: @Drew I admit that not all minds think in the same way but the question seems clearly stated as a starting point. In general, words and thoughts are inextricably entwined; they do not necessarily follow in any sequence and to seek such is often illusory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [Smart Aleck](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smart%20aleck) fits your context:

> an obnoxiously conceited and self-assertive person with pretensions to smartness or cleverness.

(M-W)

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect!

Comment: The term *smart Alec* can also be applied to intelligent people. The term is usually about the person's attitude, not whether they actually are smart or not."